# Meteorjs: How to download attachment from response to .csv file?

Tags: ajax, csv, meteor

I'm having trouble saving to a .csv file from a response returned from a POST call in Meteorjs.

Relevant headers from the response:

`content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8.`

`content-disposition: attachment;filename=Dashboard.xlsx`

`content-encoding: gzip`

Content from the response: `'\u001f�\b\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0003\u0002\u0000\u0000\u0000��\u0003\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000'`

`file.write(response.content);` just pipes that gibberish to a csv.

As an alternative, I'm thinking I can just spawn a child process and curl.

Comment: It looks like the file you're getting is in `.xlsx` format instead of `.csv`, are you sure you're not missing some parameter for format definition in your request?

Answer (score 1):

I interpret your question like this:

> I want to return a CSV that can be used by Excel.

You can create a route for this.

```
Router.route('/yourpath/csv', {
    where: 'server',
    name: 'csvRoute',
    action: function () {
        var filename = 'foo.csv';
        var fileData = '\ufeff'; // Add unicode signature for Excel.
        fileData += "header1;header2;"; // headers

        // headers so that the browser knows what to do.
        var headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;',
            'Content-Disposition': "attachment; filename=" + filename
        };

        // fill with content.
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            fileData += "value1_" + i + ";value2_" + i + ";"
            fileData += "\r\n";
        }
        this.response.writeHead(200, headers);
        return this.response.end(fileData);
    }
});
```

This will return a CSV that you can open in Excel.

```
<a target="_blank" href="{{pathFor 'csvRoute'}}">Download CSV</a>
```

Now I noticed that you said that you did a POST and not a GET. But the theory is the same.

Comment: Sorry - should've clarified a bit more: The response is from an external server and I want to store the content of the response into a .csv file.

Comment: My bad. Sorry. Then my answer will not help you. Good luck anyways!